Asserting a list item is equal to one of two options in AssertJ
I'm using AssertJ for assertions in an integration test.
I have a List<String> where each item in the list has one of two possible expected values, and each of these match sets is unique to the item. I don't care about list item ordering, but there should be a 1:1 relationship between items and match sets. For example, given the expected data:

Expected:
"A-1" OR "A-2"
"B-1" OR "B-2"
"C-1" OR "C-2"

We should succeed with actual data like:

Actual (happy path)
"A-1"
"B-2"
"C-1"
Actual (order doesn't matter)
"C-2"
"A-2"
"B-1"

But fail with actual data like:

Actual ("A-*" can't be matched twice, "B-*" was never matched.):
"A-1"
"A-2"
"C-1"

Actual ("D-1" doesn't match, more actual items than expected items.):
"A-1"
"B-2"
"C-1"
"D-1"

Actual ("B-3" doesn't match.):
"A-1"
"B-3"
"C-1"

Actual (More expected items than actual.):
"A-1"
"B-2"


I'm trying to find an elegant way of making this assertion.
My first attempt was:
var actual = List.of("A-1", "B-2", "C-1");

assertThat(actual).satisfiesExactlyInAnyOrder(
    s -> assertThat(s).matches(Pattern.complile("A-(1|2)")),
    s -> assertThat(s).matches(Pattern.complile("B-(1|2)")),
    s -> assertThat(s).matches(Pattern.complile("C-(1|2)"))
);

Which is ok, but is specific to strings and regex.
(and in my actual case the two options have little overlap so the pattern is basically `"(Option1|Option2)" making regex feel like a hack)
After some doc reading and brain teasing I remembered the isIn() assert and refined it to this:
var actual = List.of("A-1", "B-2", "C-1");

assertThat(actual).satisfiesExactlyInAnyOrder(
    s -> assertThat(s).isIn("A-1", "A-2"),
    s -> assertThat(s).isIn("B-1", "B-2"),
    s -> assertThat(s).isIn("C-1", "C-2")
);

I like this more for its explicitness.
What I wish is that there was some way of avoiding the need to cut Lambdas for each condition.
I can make it smoother in the tests with a helper method to generate the assert Consumer<String>s:
// UtilClass
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static Consumer<String>[] assertsFor(final List<String> prefixes) {
    final var consumers = prefixes.stream().<Consumer<String>>map(
            prefix -> (String s) -> assertThat(s).isIn(prefix + "-1", prefix + "-2")
    ).toList();
    return consumers.toArray(Consumer[]::new);
}



// test class
var actual = List.of("A-1", "B-2", "C-1");
var expectedPrefixes = List.of("A", "B", "C");

assertThat(actual).satisfiesExactlyInAnyOrder(UtilClass.assertsFor(expectedPrefixes));

But I'm wondering if there's some feature of AssertJ I'm missing that would make this whole process easier.

isIn(...) is likely your best shot right now. The lambda is necessary to move the focus to the list element, and, as of today, the lambda parameter must be wrapped with assertThat. We had some requests to provide the flexibility of writing s -> s.isIn(...), but there are implications that we couldn't solve yet. For this reason, this option is not yet offered.
